# Can Recording and save files to my app server in livekit

Tags: recording, livekit

I found this document [link](https://docs.livekit.io/server/egress/)

but it only uploaded to any S3 compatible storage, Azure, GCP, or Ali OSS.
Is there a way to upload file to my app server without using a 3rd party as instructed.